# Error when using IsRequired on DbGeography type when running add-migration command in EF5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I have a fluent API mapping class for doing code first migrations in EF 5.  When I add the following:

```
 this.Property(t => t.LocationGeography)
            .IsRequired();
```

I get an error when trying to run the add-migration command in PM console. The error is 'The given key was not present in the dictionary.'

Note: I haven't had this issue with any of my other required columns, so I am thinking it has something to do with how DbGeography is handled in migrations for EF5.  If I leave out the IsRequired method on this property in the mapping file, it successfully creates the column in SQL as a Geography type, but it is nullable (which I am trying to make not nullable).

UPDATE: I decided to update the database to required manually, and then use EF power tools to reverse engineer what I did to see how they tried to accomplish this task.  The mapping file did not add a required attribute or mapping to the property.  When applied, it was nullable.  I am starting to think this is not yet supported.